# How to embed a Google Map into a Meetup announcement?

Tags: google-maps, meetup

I just started a group on Meetup. Google provides HTML code to embed a map, pinpointing a specific location, into a page. Here's an example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3889.1461207675725!2d100.86508471474268!3d12.898324219972073!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x310296f531949d27%3A0x6e340507013124ba!2sThanon+Jomtiensaineung%2C+Muang+Pattaya%2C+Amphoe+Bang+Lamung%2C+Chang+Wat+Chon+Buri+20150!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sth!4v1511792968634" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is there a way to use this Google HTML to embed a map into a Meetup announcement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meetup doesn't support embedding iframes into descriptions, but you can enter the address in the venue form and it will produce a link to Google Maps for you.